# Books to start with big data

Tags: mongodb, nosql, hadoop

I would like to start learning about the big data technologies. I work in this area in the future. Does anyone know good books to start learning about it? Hadoop, HBase.

Beginner -
intermediate -
advanced -

Thanks in advance

Comment: Things change faster than books are being written. Better search online. http://nosql.mypopescu.com/ is a good point of contact.

Comment: Aside from big data is only a buzzword, big data and NoSQL are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

The first primer which will save you research is by Martin Fowler.
[NoSQL Distilled](http://martinfowler.com/books/nosql.html).  Available on Kindle from Amazon.

Reviews the types of NoSQL databases.

- Key Value Pair {Redis, Raik}, Uses {Web Sessions, Shopping Cart, User Profiles}
- Document {MongoDB, CouchDB...}, Uses {EventLogging, CMS, Blog}
- Column {Cassandra, Hbase...}, Uses {EventLogging, CMS, Blog}
- Graph {Neo4j,FlockDB...},Uses {Connected data, location based}

Each of the databases have specific use cases.  Document and Column will store more of Domain models like you would see in your code.  (Customer, Orders, OrderDetails)

You can get Mongo Up and running in short order.
View at [docs.mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/)
- Windows
- OSX
- Linux

Once you code up a few command line apps to push data and query it out you can start to build your RESTful services against the mongodB.

To move to the intermediate and advanced you can visit 10gen for Videos and books for monogdB.

mongly.com - Has some free items for you to read as well.

Start with one NoSQL and then you can move to a few others.  Document and Column would be a good starting point, we choose mongo and then Redis.  That's the path we took when moving off of SQL Server.